# Write a program to find the minimum of a sequence of nonnegative numbers entered

Tags: c#

I have trouble with the logic in the `GetMinimumNumber()`. I know I have to assign a number to minimum to get everything started but somehow I always end up with zero when I do.

```
namespace Num16
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int minimum = 0, userInput;

            //call GetUserInput and pass a string prompt to it
            userInput = GetUserInput("Enter the first number or -1 to quit.");

            //determine if the program should procede.
            while (userInput >= 0)
            {
                minimum = GetMinimumNumber(userInput,minimum);
                userInput = GetUserInput("Enter the next number or -1 to quit.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The minimum is: {0}",minimum);
        }//end main()

        public static int GetMinimumNumber(int userInput, int minimum)
        {
            int a, b;
            if (userInput < minimum )
            {
                minimum = userInput;
                return minimum;
            }
            else
            {
                return userInput;
            }

        }//end GetMinimumNumber()

        public static int GetUserInput(string prompt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            return int.Parse (Console.ReadLine());

        }//end GetUserInput()
    }
}
```

Why does it always return 0?

Comment: Walk through the execution of the program in your mind. You begin by setting `minimum` to 0. The user then enters a number, say, 1. What does GetMinimumNumber do?

Comment: What values have you tried?  Not positive numbers I hope? :)

Comment: Also, you declare a and b and then never used them.  You should remove that line.

Comment: If you've written a program and you don't understand how it works, today would be a good day to learn how to use a debugger. Step through the program one line at a time; before every step, make a prediction in your mind about what that step will do, and **why that effect furthers the goal of the program**. Eventually you will not be able to do so correctly, and then you will know what is wrong with how you've thought about the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `minimum` to 0, and you only compare it to numbers that are positive. So there is never a number that is less than `minimum`, and minimum remains 0.

You should initialize minimum to `int.MaxValue` instead.

Comment: Im unable to up vote but that worked. Ill continue to work with the logic and try to figure it out whilst minimum = 0 though. Thank you.

Comment: @DenisVoituron, that's what I'd usually do, but the OP seems to be a beginner, so I thought it would be more useful to him to explain what was wrong in his algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 7, -2, 3};
int min = numbers.Min();
Console.WriteLine(min);
```

Comment: Maybe you **can** use LINQ. But I would argue that this doesn't answer the question "*Why does it always return 0?*"